# problem converting php code to python generating password digest for soap requests

Tags: python, php, password-encryption, password-hash

```
<?php
$password = "SECRETPASSWORD";
$nonce = random_bytes(32); # requires PHP 7
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$timestamp = date(DATE_ATOM);
$encodedNonce = base64_encode($nonce);
$passSHA = base64_encode(sha1($nonce . $timestamp . sha1($password, true), true));
?>
```

it generates the below result with a *28 characters password digest*, which I am using in soap requests, and it works fine

```
password_digest = '/pBYmwwc2cM87CUr8oB4Wkmyc0Q='
nonce = '���>�!��g��q�[�`�R��=J�o�'
nonce_base_64_encode = 'uqbkProhsR3JZxjC93HWW8BghQFSgqo9Sv9vGgUa4hs='
timestamp = '2022-01-13T18:28:52+00:00'
```

I need to do this same in python, but python is somehow generating longer password_digest and the soap request fails. I don't know if I am not generating the random_bytes correctly in python or some other issue. Below is python code:

```
import secrets
import hashlib
import datetime

clearPassword = 'MYSECRETPASSWORD'
created_at_timestamp_utc = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")


def getSha1String(string):
    stringInBytes = string.encode('ascii')
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(stringInBytes)
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
    return hex_dig

def getBase64NonceString(nonce):
    nonce_bytes = nonce.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(nonce_bytes)
    base64_nonce = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
    return base64_nonce

def getBase64String(string):
    string_bytes = string.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(string_bytes)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
    return base64_string

nonce =  secrets.token_bytes(32)
base64_nonce = getBase64Nonce(nonce)
sha1_password = getSha1String(clearPassword)
password_digest = getBase64String(getSha1String(str(nonce) + created_at_timestamp_utc + sha1_password))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python code has 3 problems:

1. You're using binary output from `sha1()` in PHP, but hex output in python. Use `digest()`, not `hexdigest()`. This is why your output is longer in python.
2. Your timestamp format is incorrect.

   The PHP format `DATE_ATOM` is `"Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"`, where `P` outputs the UTC offset in the format `+00:00`. Unfortunately Python's `strftime()` doesn't seem to have an equivalent, but it's all in UTC anyway and your python code simply specifies the static string `Z`. So change that to `+00:00`, otherwise your tokens won't match.

   Eg: `timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')`
3. You're using `SECRETPASSWORD` in PHP and `MYSECRETPASSWORD` in python, and I am emabarrased at how long I bashed my head against that one without noticing.

Succint working code:

```py
import hashlib, datetime, base64

password = 'SECRETPASSWORD'
timestamp = '2022-01-13T18:28:52+00:00'
nonce = base64.b64decode('uqbkProhsR3JZxjC93HWW8BghQFSgqo9Sv9vGgUa4hs=')

def quickSHA(input):
    return hashlib.sha1(input).digest()

def makeToken(password, timestamp, nonce):
    return base64.b64encode(
        quickSHA( nonce + timestamp + quickSHA(password) )
    )

print makeToken(password, timestamp, nonce)
```

Output: `/pBYmwwc2cM87CUr8oB4Wkmyc0Q=`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested your code on python2 and it is working as expected. But on python3 its not working. And giving errors. I have followed the errors and applied possible fixes. But at the end the hash generated in python3 is still very much longer. While python2 gives exactly 28 characters hash, no matter how longer the input is.

Python3 Errors:
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes ( because of nonce is in bytes )
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing ( need to convert plain password to bytes before hashing )

Comment: Finally problem solved by converting all params to bytes as suggested in this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234340/is-there-a-hash-algorithm-in-python-3-8-3-hashlib-for-the-algorithm-base64sha1?rq=1